# i have installed react bootstrap in my terminal but i have found this error

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
at module.exports (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
at handleParseError (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:449:10)
at E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:481:5
at E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:342:12
at E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
at E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
at runSyncOrAsync (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
at iterateNormalLoaders (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
at Array. (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
at Storage.finished (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
at E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
throw err;
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
at module.exports (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
at E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
at E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
at E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v20.11.1
PS E:\Farooq\Software Development\React JS Project\ReactWebSite\react_website\public>

i want to resolve this issue